# Network in Network in keras implementation

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, keras

I have implemented a keras version of Network in Network Paper for Image Classification for college assignment but when I am running it in my system hangs.

I would like to know whether I have implemented it properly according to architecture, loss function, layers etc as am I new to deep learning and I couldn't find any proper figure stating the number filters in each layer. The code is below.

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,AveragePooling2D,Reshape
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K

def preprocess():
    (x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train),28,28, 1))
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test),28,28, 1))
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train,10)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test,10)

    return (x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test)

def model(x):
    x1 = Conv2D(11,(1,1),padding = 'same')(x)
    x1 = Flatten()(x1)
    x1 = Dense(900,activation = 'relu')(x1)
    x1 = Dense(900,activation = 'relu')(x1)
    x1 = Reshape((30,30,1),input_shape = x1.shape)(x1)
    x1 = Conv2D(11,(1,1),padding = 'same')(x1)
    x1 = Flatten()(x1)
    x1 = Dense(400,activation = 'relu')(x1)
    x1 = Dense(400,activation = 'relu')(x1)
    x1 = Reshape((20,20,1),input_shape = x1.shape)(x1)
    x1 = Conv2D(11,(1,1),padding = 'same')(x1)
    x1 = Flatten()(x1)
    x1 = Dense(100,activation = 'relu')(x1)
    x1 = Dense(100,activation = 'relu')(x1)
    x1 = Reshape((10,10,1),input_shape = x1.shape)(x1)
    x1 = Conv2D(11,(1,1),padding = 'same')(x1)
    x1 = AveragePooling2D((2,2),padding = 'same')(x1)
    x1 = Flatten()(x1)
    x1 = Dense(10)(x1)
    output = Activation('softmax')(x1)
    return output

input_img = Input(shape = (28,28,1))
NiN = Model(input_img,model(input_img))
NiN.compile(optimizer='adadelta',loss = 'mean_absolute_percentage_error')
x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test = preprocess()
NiN.fit(x_train,y_train,
            epochs=10,
            batch_size=128,
            shuffle=True)
```

Comment: You have used a lot of dense layers which are very computationally expensive. I suggest you to divide your network arcitecture in the following way : `Conv->relu->Conv->Relu :::::::::::::::::::Flatten->Dense->Dense`

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply The Authors of network in network model have suggested to used fully Connected layer in between Convolutional layers to create more dense representations as I am specifically Implementing NiN it won't appropriate to add Dense layers in the end.

Comment: Curious why you used FC with softmax at the top of the network if you were trying to follow the paper closely. The authors use `GlobalAveragePooling2D` with softmax at the top of the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your implementation and changed the loss function to 'categorical_crossentropy' (used for classification where classes are mutually exclusive) and the optimizer to 'Adam'. Seems to run smooth now.

Comment: Ya thanks, I did change the error function 4 months back but I never tested it with Adam

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry to say but your implementation is nowhere close to the NiN paper implementation. I just wrote the Keras code which, to my best knowledge, closely approximates the method used in the paper. I get `0.54%` Test Error on MNIST which is close enough to their `0.47%`. Further hyperparameter tuning would improve my result.

```
def NiNBlock(kernel, mlps, strides):
    def inner(x):
        l = Conv2D(mlps[0], kernel, strides=strides, padding='same')(x)
        l = Activation('relu')(l)
        for size in mlps[1:]:
            l = Conv2D(size, 1, strides=[1,1])(l)
            l = Activation('relu')(l)
        return l
    return inner


def get_model(img_rows, img_cols):
    img = Input(shape=(img_rows, img_cols, 1))
    l1 = NiNBlock(5, [192, 160, 96], [1,1])(img)
    l1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(l1)
    l1 = Dropout(0.7)(l1)

    l2 = NiNBlock(5, [192, 192, 192], [1,1])(l1)
    l2 = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(l2)
    l2 = Dropout(0.7)(l2)

    l3 = NiNBlock(3, [192, 192, 10], [1,1])(l2)

    l4 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(l3)
    l4 = Activation('softmax')(l4)

    model = Model(inputs=img, outputs=l4)
    return model

model = get_model(img_rows, img_cols)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model_name = 'NiN_mnist'
filepath = "{}.weights.best.hdf5".format(model_name)
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, 
save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=epochs,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
      callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the sharing the results and implementation I guess this'll the people who reach out to this post for NiN implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

The above two functions including the consecutive assignment statements that are too complex. I think that the recursion is more elegant and powerful. In addition, it is much easier to be understood.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


def nin(input_shape):
    # Define Network in Network model
    input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu')(input)
    x = Conv2D(filters=160, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu')(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(2, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu')(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(2, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=10, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu')(x)

    output = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

    model = Model(input, output)

    return model 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    model = nin(input_shape=(28,28,1))

    model.summary()
```